# Hook woocommerce price in backend order edition

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin, hooks

I need to change item product prices in Woocommerce **Backend** Order. I tried tu use the following hook, but I have a problem trying to obtain the **order id**. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

```
function my_custom_prices ($price, $product)
{
    if ( !is_admin() || ( is_admin() && is_post_type_archive() ) ) return $price;

    global $post, $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
    $user_id = $order->user_id; 
    $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

    if ( in_array( 'my_role', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        return $price * 2; 
    }
    else {
        return $price;
    }

}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'my_custom_prices ', 10, 2);
```

**Complete problem:**

The complete problem is as follows. I am using a plugin that adds a field to the product called wholesale price. If the customer has the wholesale customer role, the order uses those prices. The plugin works fine, but it does not take the price in the backend. I talked to the author and it's something they do not plan to change yet. My client needs to modify the orders. But when it enters the backend, it takes the common price, not the wholesaler. I need to do something in the backend that allows me to detect if the order is from a client with a wholesale customer role. If yes, take the correct price when adding products. There is more information on the discussion with the author here. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wholesale-prices-in-backend-editing-orders/ Thank you very much for the help you can give me.

**Options:**

**woocommerce_get_price**: does not work because I cannot obtain the customer id

**woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta**: nice option, but I could not find a sample

**Button**: nice option, but I do not know how can I change the price. I tryed the follow:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons', 'action_aplicar_mayoristas', 10, 1);

function action_aplicar_mayoristas( $order )
{
    echo '<button type="button" onclick="document.post.submit();" class="button button-primary generate-items">Aplicar precios mayoristas</button>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="1" name="aplicar_mayoristas" />';
};

add_action('save_post', 'aplicar_mayoristas', 10, 3);

function aplicar_mayoristas($post_id, $post, $update){
    $slug = 'shop_order';
    if(is_admin()){
            if ( $slug != $post->post_type ) {
                    return;
            }
            if(isset($_POST['aplicar_mayoristas']) && $_POST['aplicar_mayoristas']){


$order = wc_get_order( $post_id); 
//$order_id = $order->get_user_id();

// Iterating through each "line" items in the order
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {

   //$item_data->set_subtotal("798");
   $item_data->set_price("798");
//->set_price($custom_price);
}


                }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to change price when the administrator manually add a product to an order ?

Comment: Yes. But I need to get the customer id for a business rule.

Comment: you can use the action `woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta`. this action is thrown just after the product is added in the order then you need to edit the product in the order on this action.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have sample code?

Comment: Aded more info...

Comment: I found the code at the following page helpful: https://www.buzzphp.com/posts/woocommerce-update-price-when-added-by-admin-via-wp-admin